# Decode and get data of JS object in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json, object, stringify

I have a variable named

```
var type = [];
```

where i do

```
type.push({'type' : 1});
```

and finally i get the following object:

```
[{"type":"1"},{"type":"2"},{"type":"3"},{"type":"4"}]
```

by doing JSON.stringify();

but how can i get the type inside PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$object = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: working code:

   $types = json_decode($this->types);
   echo $types[0]->type;

thank you